# AWS SMTP From email address for sent messages - restrictions

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy, amazon-ses

I have a Delphi 10.4 Firemonkey app that needs to allow users to send emails. The email messages must be displayed in HTML and contain links. Indy seems to meet those requirements.

It's important that the email messages look like they are from the actual sending user, and that the receiver be able to use the Reply function to respond to the message. All the Indy docs I've found show that I can enter a From email address to be included with sent messages. However, I'm an AWS customer and I plan to use the AWS SMTP server. Unfortunately, AWS SMTP docs seem to say that messages it sends must be from email address domains owned by the AWS account using the SMTP service.

Am I correct in concluding that email messages sent by AWS SMTP must appear to be from an email address associated with my company, rather than the user's actual email address? If so, is this typical of SMTP services or peculiar to AWS? Should I look for another SMTP service provider that allows me to specify the From email address?

Thanks

Comment: And your question regarding programming is...? Why not seeking support at Amazon to ask all your questions? Remember that opion-based questions are not allowed.

Comment: You can set different eMail address in `ReplyTo` property of your message in order to control to which eMail address the massage will be replied to.

Comment: You can also specify a `Sender` that is different than the user. So you can show that the email is `From` the user, but is being relayed via you as the `Sender`.

Comment: I can't comment specifically on AWS, but check out SPF, DMARC and DKIM.  If a domain has published policies that you don't comply with on sending then you should expect that receivers will discard your messages.  SMTP uses a MAIL FROM command (also referred to as the 'envelope' sender which does not have to be the same as the 'From' header or the 'ReplyTo' header.

Comment: Thank you. @Remy. That's just the kind of thing I needed to know.

Comment: To expand on what Rob said - when `TIdSMTP` sends the `MAIL FROM` command, it will specify the email's `Sender` if provided, otherwise it will specify the email's `From` instead.